# How to add conditional html input into string output is google search query

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, input, conditional-statements

I'm pretty new in Python and stumbling across something that looks not to hard but for me it is.

I ask user different user inputs via html (with flask) and want to combine this into a variable so i can return an google search url. I have 45 different input fields and none of them are required.

I've tried this with 3 variables but unfortunately it doesn't work. Next step will be adding search operators like "", and, or, +, -,

```
if var1 == " ":
    pass
else:
    var1 = var1+"+"

if var2 == " ":
    pass
else:
    var2 = var2+"+"

if var3 == " ":
    pass
else:
    var3 = var3+"+"

url = ("http://gogle.com#q="var1+var2+var3)
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Use F string. Here is an example:

```
varOne = 'varone'
varTwo = 'vartwo'
varThree = 'varthree'

combined_url = f'{varOne}?{varTwo}?{varThree}'

print(combined_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlencode()` from `urllib.parse` to generate the URL:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlencode

var1 = '1 2 3'
var2 = 'a/b/c'
var3 = 'd&e?f'

variables = {'x': var1,'y': var2,'z': var3}

url = 'http://google.com/?' + urlencode(variables)

print(url)
# output : 
# http://google.com/?x=1+2+3&y=a%2Fb%2Fc&z=d%26e%3Ff
```